# Sending ether to my smart contract: function payable keyword or fallback function,

Tags: solidity

Between the two options to send ether to my smart contract, which is best to use or are they same

Comment: I would recommend researching the subject first - searching `ethereum fallback payable` or something like it should be a good place to start, and coming back with more specific questions. If you've already researched, feel free to edit the question to add more detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The end result is the same. It's just a matter of context.

Typically, you should avoid relying on a fallback function (or, more precisely, the `receive` function). A fallback function is only called if the call fails to be routed to any other function in the contract - probably because it either calls a function which doesn't exist or it doesn't call a function at all.

So if you know what you are doing you should use a regular named `payable` function and call that. But if someone isn't sure what functionality a contract supports and/or doesn't really know what they are doing, they'll probably end up calling the fallback function.

If you don't have a fallback function and someone tries to call a non-existing function with Ether the transaction will revert.